# Symfony 2.3. login by username or email

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I want to user can login by username or email. According the [document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) My security.yml code is

```
providers:
     entity_members:
        entity: 
            class: AcmeBundle:Members
```

it gives the error

**The Doctrine repository “Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository” must implement UserProviderInterface** 
if append the entity providers by

```
property: username
```

then i can login only by user name not email my repository class is

```
        namespace PropertyMart\UserBundle\Entity;

        use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
        use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
        use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
        use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
        use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
        use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

        class MembersRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
        {
            public function loadUserByUsername($username)
            {
                $q = $this
                    ->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
                    ->setParameter('username', $username)
                    ->setParameter('email', $username)
                    ->getQuery()
                ;

                try {
                    // The Query::getSingleResult() method throws an exception
                    // if there is no record matching the criteria.
                    $user = $q->getSingleResult();
                } catch (NoResultException $e) {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Unable to find an active admin UserBundle:User object identified by "%s".', $username), null, 0, $e);
                }

                return $user;
            }

            public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
            {
                $class = get_class($user);
                if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
                    throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', $class));
                }

                return $this->find($user->getId());
            }

            public function supportsClass($class)
            {
                return $this->getEntityName() === $class || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
            }
        }
```

unable to short out the problem ..... security.yml without property:username was working in symfony 2.1*

Answer (score 3):

Your 'Members' Entity class must implement UserInterface.

Ex:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class Members implements UserInterface
{
 //.......
}
```